# Section of a Linear Surjection

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, algebraic-topology, continuity

Consider a surjective linear map $L_A:\mathbb{R}^{D}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$, where (obviously) $D> d$, given by $L_A:x\mapsto Ax$ for some $d\times D$-matrix $A$.  Are there simple conditions for there to exist a continuous (possibly linear) map
$$
R_A:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^D \mbox{ satisfying } L_A\circ R_A(x)=x \qquad (\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d)?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the short exact sequence $$0\rightarrow \operatorname{Ker }L_A \rightarrow \mathbb R^D \xrightarrow{L_A} \mathbb R^d \rightarrow 0$$
What you are asking for is if this s.e.s has a right split. Indeed it does since $\mathbb R$ is a field and all $\mathbb R$-modules are free.

Comment: Right!  So this holds and its splits in $\mathbb{R}-\operatorname{Mod}_{fin}$ (finite-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-modules).  Since $\mathbb{R}^D$ is finite-dimensional then it is continuous when $\mathbb{R}^D$ and $\mathbb{R}^d$ have normed topologies?

Comment: yes all linear maps between finite-dimensional normed spaces are continuous.